# Casting objects to subclasses of a Parcelable superclass?

Tags: java, android, parcelable, serializable

Okay, so I have a class `SomeClass` that is `Parcelable`.

It has an array of another `Parcelable` class called `SuperClass`. In my constructor for `SomeClass`, I'm trying to read the array of the `SuperClass` objects into the `myArray` instance variable. This would be straightforward; however:

`SuperClass` has two subclasses `FirstSubClass` and `SecondSubClass`. The array `temp` is supposed to have a mixture of all 3, but for some reason it has only `SuperClass` objects (the `if` and `else if` statements don't seem to execute since none of the elements of `temp` are instances of the subclasses).

```
public SomeClass(Parcel in) {

    myArray = new SuperClass[100];

    // this is probably where the problem is due to the classloader parameter:
    Object[] temp = in.readArray(SuperClass.class.getClassLoader());

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        if(temp[i] instanceof FirstSubClass)
            myArray[i] = (FirstSubClass) temp[i];

        else if(temp[i] instanceof SecondSubClass)
            myArray[i] = (SecondSubClass) temp[i];

        else
            myArray[i] = (SuperClass) temp[i];
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can read the elements of an array of parcelable objects such that the subclasses of this object aren't automatically casted up to the superclass.

(I think I may have worded my question very confusingly, please tell me if I did).

Comment: Is Parcelable an interface or super class?  Is that the same as the Parcel that SomeClass takes in its constructor?

Comment: `Parcelable` is an interface that both `SomeClass` and `SuperClass` implement. `Parcel` is a class.

Comment: How do you write to the parcel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and I couldn't ... I used `writeParcelableArray` and **NOT** `writeTypedArray`. Here are the classes that I've create:

```
public class SuperClass implements Parcelable {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SuperClass> CREATOR = new Creator<SuperClass>() {

        @Override
        public SuperClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SuperClass[size];
        }

        @Override
        public SuperClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SuperClass(source);
        }
    };

    private String label;

    public SuperClass() {
    }

    protected SuperClass(Parcel source) {
        label = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(label);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And its child classes:

```
public class FirstSubClass extends SuperClass {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<FirstSubClass> CREATOR = new Creator<FirstSubClass>() {

        @Override
        public FirstSubClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FirstSubClass[size];
        }

        @Override
        public FirstSubClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new FirstSubClass(source);
        }
    };

    public FirstSubClass() {
        super();
    }

    public FirstSubClass(Parcel source) {
        super(source);
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class SecondSubClass extends SuperClass {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SecondSubClass> CREATOR = new Creator<SecondSubClass>() {

        @Override
        public SecondSubClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SecondSubClass[size];
        }

        @Override
        public SecondSubClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SecondSubClass(source);
        }
    };

    public SecondSubClass() {
        super();
    }

    public SecondSubClass(Parcel source) {
        super(source);
    }

}
```

and the `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass implements Parcelable {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SomeClass> CREATOR = new Creator<SomeClass>() {

        @Override
        public SomeClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SomeClass[size];
        }

        @Override
        public SomeClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SomeClass(source);
        }
    };

    private String name;
    private SuperClass[] array;

    public SomeClass(String name, SuperClass[] array) {
        this.name = name;
        this.array = array;
    }

    protected SomeClass(Parcel source) {
        this.name = source.readString();
        Parcelable[] temp = source.readParcelableArray(SuperClass.class.getClassLoader());
        array = new SuperClass[temp.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (SuperClass) temp[i];
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
        if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
            sb.append(" Array is empty");
        } else {
            sb.append(" Array:");
            for (SuperClass sc : array) {
                sb.append(sc.getClass().getSimpleName());
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public SuperClass[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeParcelableArray(array, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

From an activity I tap a button, create a `SomeClass` object, attach to an intent that I start a new Activity and from there I log the passed value. The function that starts the activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SuperClass[] array = new SuperClass[] { new SuperClass(), new FirstSubClass(), new SecondSubClass(), new SuperClass() };
    SomeClass cl = new SomeClass("My Label", array);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("PASS", cl);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and from `NextActivity`:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set some content if you wish
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Passed value: " + getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PASS"));
    }
}
```

I can see in the logs:

```
Passed value: My Label Array:SuperClass,FirstSubClass,SecondSubClass,SuperClass
```

Exactly what I passed from previous activity ... Check the differences from your code, I suspect you didn't write a `CREATOR` for `FirstSubClass` and `SecondSubClass`

Comment: I have `CREATOR` variables in all 3 of the classes, so that can't be it. I'll try comparing the rest of your code to my classes; if I still can't find the problem, i'll post my code - thanks for the help!

Comment: I found the problem after going through your code a few times! The problem was that I was using the method `writeTypedArray` rather than `writeParcelableArray`, which allows for arrays with multiple types of objects to be passed through; could you update your answer to highlight that this is the solution just in case anyone else has this problem?

Comment: my Super Class is an abstract Class.. what do you think should i do for my structure..?

Comment: Thanks, nice solution!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you needed to get the classloader in the readArray method but I took a shot and making an example of your code - so there are several pieces of code for the entire example.

Sample Parcelable class - base class for some other in the example

```
/**
 */
public class Parcelable {

public String parcel() {
    return "in Parcelable.parcel()...";
    }
}
```

Example SomeClass - changed to force the array to match the hard-code size I returned from Parcel class.  If the array contains only those types, then you can just cast to Parcelable instead of having to cast to FirstSubClass, SecondSubClass and SuperClass.

```
/**
 */
public class SomeClass extends Parcelable {

private Parcelable[] myArray;

public SomeClass(Parcel in) {
    myArray = new SuperClass[3];
    // this is probably where the problem is due to the classloader parameter:
    //Object[] temp = in.readArray(SuperClass.class.getClassLoader());
    Object[] temp = in.readArray();

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(temp[i] instanceof FirstSubClass)
            myArray[i] = (FirstSubClass) temp[i];
        else if(temp[i] instanceof SecondSubClass)
            myArray[i] = (SecondSubClass) temp[i];
        else
            myArray[i] = (SuperClass) temp[i];
    }*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myArray[i] = (Parcelable) temp[i];
    }
}

public String parcel() {
    return "In SomeClass.parcel()...";
}

public void show() {
    for (Parcelable p : myArray) {
        System.out.println (p.parcel());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args ){
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(new Parcel());
    sc.show();
    }
}
```

Sample Parcel class - had to fake due to no info.

```
/**
 */
public class Parcel {

public Object[] readArray() {
    Object[] array = new Object[3];
    array[0] = new SuperClass();
    array[1] = new FirstSubClass();
    array[2] = new SecondSubClass();
    return array;
    }
}
```

Sample SuperClass

```
/**
 */
public class SuperClass extends Parcelable {

public String parcel() {
    return "In SuperClass.parcel()...";
    }
}
```

Sample FirtSubClass

```
/**
 */
public class FirstSubClass extends SuperClass {

public String parcel() {
    return "In FirstSubClass.parcel()...";
    }
}
```

Sample SecondSubClass

```
/**
 */
public class SecondSubClass extends SuperClass {

public String parcel() {
    return "In SecondSubClass.parcel()...";
    }
}
```